# I need to read every line, and to create an empty file after reading each and every line

Tags: shell-script, shell

Contents of `file.txt`:

```
apple
mango
orange
```

My script should read `apple` and create a zero byte file `apple.txt` then `mango.txt` file.

Could someone help, please?

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `xargs`:

```
sed 's/$/.txt/' < file | xargs -rd '\n' touch --
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like can do the work

```
while read a
do
touch "${a}.txt"
done <file.txt
```

But you can have problems if you in file line with space or special symbol inside.

To avoid problems with backslash in words/files you can use this code:

```
while read -r a
do
touch "${a}.txt"
done <file.txt
```

Comment: Spaces will not be an issue, but backslashes will be, unless you use `read -r`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, will add it as option, thank you :)

Comment: @Kusalananda, leading and trailing spaces and tabs will still be an issue unless you remove them from `$IFS`. Leading `-` characters will also be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read filename; do > ${filename}.txt; done < file.txt
```